# Search bar is refreshing the index of my table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm working on a car rental app, which accepts user's input and putting it in my `SQLite` Database.

Inside my tableview viewcontroller, it is displaying the informations fine.

**Example:**

```
Cell 1: Toyota, Philippines, 5000
Cell 2: Nissan, America, 1000
Cell 3: Mitsubishi, England, 2000
```

The problem is, whenever I search, for example I searched the "england", the only right data it is displaying is only the location. So it will display like this:

`Cell 1: Toyota, England, 5000`

which is `Toyota` and `5000` is coming from the index `0`. and the only right data is England.

My desired result whenever I search "england":
`Cell 1: Mitsubishi, England, 2000`

Please help me fixing the car type and rate to display it also.

This is my code inside my table view controller:

```
import UIKit
import SQLite

class CarList: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, 
UISearchBarDelegate {
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet var searchBar: UISearchBar!


//variables I used to append my database
var carType = [String]()
var rate = [String]()  
var location = [String]()

//variables I used to append my filtered data for searchbar
var filteredLocation: [String]!
var filteredCar: [String]!
var filteredRate: [String]!


var img = [UIImage(named: "Toyota"), UIImage(named: "Nissan")]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    searchBar.placeholder = "Search Location"


    do{

        let documentDirectory = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)

        let fileUrl = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("users").appendingPathExtension("sqlite3")
        let database = try Connection(fileUrl.path)
        Variables.database = database

    }catch {
        print(error)
    }


    //appending my database to my array

    do{

        let users = try Variables.database.prepare(Variables.rTable)

        for user in users {

            carType.append(user[Variables.rCar])
            rate.append(user[Variables.rRate])
            location.append(user[Variables.rLocation])         
        }

    }catch{
        print(error)
    }
    searchBar.delegate = self

//assigning the array to filtered data

    filteredLocation = location
    filteredCar = carType
    filteredRate = rate    
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return filteredLocation.count

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CarListCell

    cell.carType.text = "Car Type: " + filteredCar[indexPath.row]
    cell.rate.text = "Location: " + filteredLocation[indexPath.row]
    cell.carImage.image = UIImage(named: filteredCar[indexPath.row]+".jpg")
    return (cell)

}


func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    filteredLocation = searchText.isEmpty ? location : location.filter({(dataString: String) -> Bool in


        return dataString.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil



    })

    tableView.reloadData()

}


//below is the code when I clicked on the table view cell, it will pass the data. 
//but the filtered location is the only one working.

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "info" {

        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {

        let controller = segue.destination as! CarInfo

        controller.getCar = filteredCar[indexPath.row]
        controller.getRate = filteredRate[indexPath.row]
        controller.getLocation = filteredLocation[indexPath.row]

        }
    }
}   
} // End Class
```

And this is my database table in case you need it, I separated it using Variables.swift.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SQLite

class Variables: UIViewController{

    var database: Connection!

    let rTable = Table("rTable")
    let rId = Expression<Int>("rId")
    let rCar= Expression<String>("rCar")
    let rLocation = Expression<String>("rLocation")
    let rRate = Expression<String>("rRate")

}
```

Comment: Where you use filteredData variable ?

Comment: sorry that is supposed to be filteredLocation, but originally filteredData but I edited it to explain it easily.

Comment: Ok the problem is the location and car type are separated from Country so you should make them object

Comment: you mean the RATE and car type? how to make them object? can you elaborate more?

Comment: I mean object called car has this properties like Class Car { var carType:String? ; var rate:String?;var location;} and then make array of car object so you will not need 3 arrays it will be just one array

Comment: sorry i can't understand what you mean. can you give me the code? I am new to swift/xcode programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than make 3 arrays for your data, you can make object for them

```
class Car{
var carType:String?
var location:String?
var rate:String?
}
```

Then rather

```
var filteredLocation: [String]!
var filteredCar: [String]!
var filteredRate: [String]!
```

make this

```
var cars = [Car]()
```

and rather than

```
 for user in users {

            carType.append(user[Variables.rCar])
            rate.append(user[Variables.rRate])
            location.append(user[Variables.rLocation])         
        }
```

make this

```
 for user in users {
          let car = Car()
          car.carType = user[Variables.rCar]
          car.location = user[Variables.rLocation]
          car.rate = user[Variables.rRate]
          cars.append(car)      
        }
```

and cellForRow change it to

```
  cell.carType.text = "Car Type: " + cars[indexPath.row].carType
    cell.rate.text = "Location: " + cars[indexPath.row].rate
    cell.carImage.image = UIImage(named: cars[indexPath.row].carType+".jpg")
```

and the important thing is that

```
filteredCars = cars.filter{
$0.carType.lowercased == searchText.lowercased}
}
```

where filteredCars is array of car object . Hope this help you .

Comment: where do i put filteredCars = cars.filter{
$0.carType.lowercased == searchText.lowercased}
}

Comment: in searchBar method rather than filteredLocation = searchText.isEmpty ? location : location.filter({(dataString: String) -> Bool in
        return dataString.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
    })

Comment: and inside numberOfRowsInSection method i will return the cars.count right? thank you so much!